# sort XSL file with javascript function

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, filter

I want to filter my XSL stylesheet by the current date so that only the entries with the current date are displayed.
I get the current date with a simple javascript function:

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="myJavaScript">
<![CDATA[
    function getDate() {
        var today = new Date();
        var d = today.getDate();
        var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = today.getFullYear();

        var year = d + "." + m + "." + y;
        return year;
    }
]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

Now I want to filter my XSL data by the current date.

I tried this, but this dont work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="logEntry">
<xsl:if expression='<xsl:value-of select="myJavaScript:getDate()"/> == 23.08.2017'>
```

Maybe anybody has an idea how I can solve this problem.
I am using XML/XSL 1.0. I know XML/XSL 2.0 has a build in function to get the current date, but I need to use version 1.0.

Thanks

Comment: Show us an example of the XML input and the expected output.

Comment: i updated the question.. I want only display the entrys with the current code.

Comment: I still don't see your input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example

Sample XML

```
<xml>
    <list output='no'>20.8.2017</list>
    <list output='no'>21.8.2017</list>
    <list output='no'>22.8.2017</list>
    <list output='yes'>23.8.2017</list>
    <list output='no'>24.8.2017</list>
</xml>
```

and this XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  
    xmlns:myJavaScript="urn:my-javascripts"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="myJavaScript">
<![CDATA[
    function getDate() {
        var today = new Date();
        var d = today.getDate();
        var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = today.getFullYear();
        var year = d + "." + m + "." + y;
        return year;
    }
]]>
</msxsl:script>


<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name='dt' select='myJavaScript:getDate()'/>
<xml>
    <xsl:attribute name='dt'><xsl:value-of select='$dt'/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:for-each select='//list[.=$dt]'>
        <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xml>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To product this result

```
<xml dt="23.8.2017" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:myJavaScr
ipt="urn:my-javascripts">
<list output="yes">23.8.2017</list>
</xml>
```

Comment: you are just amazing. thank you, it works without any issues! i will vote your answer up if i have enough Reputation for voting.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you, It was good for me too, I didn't realize you could embed a JavaScript function so easily with MSXML.  Please accept this as the answer.